# Blend background colors as they're set

Tags: css

Everybody likes when the odd and even rows in table have slightly different backgrounds to improve orientation:

[image: even and odd rows]

But sometimes, columns also need to be highlighted:

[image: highlighted columns]

Can do a trick to have those two settings automatically blend? You know, I can do it manually, by setting two colors for every class:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background-color: #CFDCFF;
}
tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: #E2E4E4;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td.result {
  background-color: #??????;
}
tr:nth-child(even) td.result {
  background-color: #??????;
}
```

But automation would make the code much more readable.

Comment: I think I could add `<div>` with transparency into the cells, but that's not what I want.

Comment: You could set the stripes as background-color for the `tr`, and then have the special `td` have an rgba background (so that the background of the `tr` underneath “shines through”) … but it still limits you to certain colors, resp. “blending down” of colors.

Comment: @CBroe Can TR have visible background? I thought it can't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the browsers I tested (Chrome, Safari, Firefox), it was possible to apply the grey and blue backgrounds to the rows themselves, and then overlay slightly transparent yellow and green backgrounds on the table cells. It looked awful though :/

```css
tr:nth-child( odd ) {
  background-color: #CFDCFF;
}

tr:nth-child( even ) {
  background-color: #E2E4E4;
}

tr > :not( :first-child ):not( :last-child ) {
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 0, .15 );
}

tr > :last-child {
  background: rgba( 0, 255, 0, .15 );
}

table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}

th, td {
    padding: .25em;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th># <th>a <th>b <th>c <th>d <th>e <th>f <th>Result
    <tr>
        <th>0 <td>0 <td>0 <td>0 <td>0 <td>0 <td>0 <td>0
    <tr>
        <th>1 <td>0 <td>0 <td>0 <td>0 <td>0 <td>1 <td>1
    <tr>
        <th>2 <td>0 <td>0 <td>0 <td>0 <td>1 <td>0 <td>1
    <tr>
        <th>3 <td>0 <td>0 <td>0 <td>0 <td>1 <td>1 <td>1
    <tr>
        <th>4 <td>0 <td>0 <td>0 <td>1 <td>0 <td>0 <td>1
```

Comment: Glad I could help - of course the aesthetic is purely a matter of opinion ;) But with these colours the distinction between elements is not so strong.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will make the code much more readable... but you can add a pseudo element in every last column cell and set an rgba background on it.
this solution have the same problem as the one suggested by @CBroe (see comments) and as he pointed out in his comment it limits you to certain colors.

here's the css anyway:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background-color: #CFDCFF;
}
tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: #E2E4E4;
}

td.results{position:relative;}
td.results:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With pseudo selectors you can make custom colors for each cell... if you still need a highlight class you can also make a color for each case

tr(odd) > td(odd),

tr(odd) > td(even),

tr(even) > td(odd)

and tr(even) > td(even)

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 1px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #aaf;
}
td:nth-child(even) {
  background: #bbf;
}
tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background: #afa;
}
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even) {
  background: #bfb;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>Item</td><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Item</td><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Item</td><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Item</td><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Item</td><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Item</td><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
</table>
```